# How can I set the brightness of the button?

Tags: xcode

In my program, there are several buttons that allows users to choose. I want to make an effect that when the users choose a button, then the button will be dimmed in order to classify that it is chosen. How it can be done? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Read this first! http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html

Comment: I agree with Joe up there.  You need to be super careful what you are doing as it sounds like you are setting up a UI that might be potentially confusing to the user.

You also used the wrong tag on this question (Xcode).  Are you doing this for MacOS or iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no brightness setting, but you can use alpha which is the visibility. 1 is visible and 0 is invisible. So do:

```
[yourButton setAlpha:0.5];
```

You can set any value between 0 and 1 so just play around with the numbers to find the best value.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that UIButton has an alpha value property that you can set to 0.5 after the user presses that button. It would look half as light up as the others around it assuming that your alpha values for the other buttons values are defaulted at 1.